# read from a serial port using even listener in a loop

Tags: java, serial-port, addeventlistener, event-listener, jssc

I have a method that write the content of a file to a serial port and then awaits the acknowledgement message. i am trying to use an even listener however no message are printed back to the console. 
however, when i read the message with out the event listener, manually in a slow pace, the messages comes back just fine.
here is my code:

```
public class portConnector {
private static SerialPort SP;


public portConnector(String pName){
    SP = new SerialPort(pName);
}

public static byte[] read(String name) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(name);     
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    inputStream.read(bytes);
    inputStream.close();
    return bytes;
}

public void push2rec (File[] LOF){
    try {
        SP.openPort();
        SP.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR;
        SP.setEventsMask(mask); 
        SP.addEventListener(new PortReader(), SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
        for (File f : LOF){
            byte[] rd = read(f.getName());
            SP.writeBytes(rd);
        }
        SP.closePort();
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {System.out.println(ex);} 
    catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
}

private static class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() == 10) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = SP.readBytes(10);
            for (byte b : buffer){
                System.out.format("%02X ", b);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in receiving string from COM-port: " + ex);
        }
    }
}}}
```

is the "addEventListener" located in the right place?
can anyone help me with this problem.
any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Are you using `javax.comm.*` classes?

Comment: No, i am using jssc.

Comment: I see. I would try removing `&& event.getEventValue()==10` and then use `byte[] buffer = SP.readBytes()` just to make it less rigid.  I would also not call `SP.closePort()` as part of the main flow. You could close the port in the event listener thereby making it conditional, rather than automatic. In your code you close it (which de-registers the listener) right after sending the content of the file.

Comment: ok. how do i write put the closePort() into the event listener?

Comment: tried it. didnt work. i dont see how the `getvalue == 10` is effecting my reading. the message suppose to be 10 bytes long, isnt getvalue should check for that length?

Comment: I merely supposed 'what if what's in the buffer is not 10 bytes exactly?'

Comment: If it is not 10 bytes then it is not the ack message and i dont care about it

Answer (score 0):

The first time your serial receive event fires it will most likely only have one character since thousands of instructions execute in a single character time.

You need to capture the characters into a buffer variable with each event until you have the 10 characters your are looking for.

You also have to  synchronize the receive event with the first character sent. That is why most serial communication is terminated with a CR or some other known character.

Comment: ok. but the main problem is that my event listener never triggered. hence i can not do any thing the data being pushed out of the receiver.

Comment: i've put a break point in the even listener method and it never reached.